# WPF merged resource dictionaries in every user control - bad idea?

Tags: wpf, resharper

I keep my app's resources in a separate DLL and reference them in my main EXE using something like this in App.xaml:-

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyThemesAssembly;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

When I edit a window that's in the main EXE project, the VS2010 designer doesn't recognise any resources from the other assembly, so I don't see any styling applied (not really an issue as I always work in the XAML view). However Resharper doesn't recognise these external resource names either, resulting in lots of squiggles under resource names when I'm editing XAML.

I've found that I can fix both the VS designer and Resharper by including the above XAML in each window and user control, but is this going to have an adverse effect on memory and/or performance? Will each window get a separate copy of the resources?

Comment: Well, the bugs in the IDE and tools shouldn't affect your code. Besides, including the resources dictionary in each and every control is an error-prone way (what if you decide to rename the dictionary? to add another one?).

Comment: I would however try to add a quirk working around the problem in design mode. (Maybe this will help: `public class MyUserControlBase : UserControl { public MyUserControlBase() { if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) LoadExternalDictionariesExplicitlyHere(); ...`)

Comment: @Vlad I've learnt to live with the squiggles - this approach of fixing Resharper is really just a "nice to have". I don't think renaming/adding resources would be an issue - in my XAML example above, "Generic.xaml" itself just merges a load of other resources in that assembly, so it's easy to add new ones. I'm more concerned about whether including that <MergedDictionaries> in each window is going to blow the memory/performance of the app (or VS2010).

Comment: The performance should not be your concern unless it really hits you. (Necessary citation about premature optimizations omitted.) However a simple workaround (like `Helpers.LoadDictionariesIfInDesignMode(this)` in each control's constructor) seems to be one-liner against multiline code in XAML :)

Comment: To fix ReSahrper you can still use `App.xaml`-defined `MergedDictionaries`, but you need to reference `MyThemesAssembly` as project, not binary reference...

Comment: @ControlFlow, I've seen that tip elsewhere but it doesn't work for me. Would it make a difference what type of project MyThemesAssembly is (it's a class library), or the build action of the xaml resources ("Page")?

Answer (score 3):

We had a problem in our application with the use of ResourceDictionaries referenced in each UserControl / View. I advise against that. We managed to reduce our application's memory footprint by like 300 mb by the use of SharedResourceDictionaries. I looks like you will end up with the ResourceDictionary being instantiated once for every single UserControl in your application. Don't do that just to fix VS designer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using VS2012.

I have a test project which I was using which I was doing resource dictionary merging from an external assembly and in my app.xaml I have this:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfPackDictionaries.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFCommonLibrary;component/Vectors/Vectors.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then in my mainwindow.xaml I have this where the path pulls in a style ModifiablePathStyle:

```
<Window xmlns:Control="clr-namespace:WPF.Common.Control;assembly=WPFCommonLibrary"  x:Class="WpfPackDictionaries.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Path Style="{StaticResource ModifiablePathStyle}" Fill="Red"/>
        <Control:Jabberwocky />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Intellisense/Resharper (V7.1 10/31 (Early Access Build)) recognizes the style and I have no squigglies:

[image]

Hence have you tried to work in VS2012?

Comment: We'll be moving to VS2012 eventually, but still waiting for the $$$ from management!

Comment: @AndrewStephens All the best work is done in deference of management. ;-)

Comment: @AndrewStephens Use VS2012 Express edition for your xaml work. It can still compile .Net 3.5/4.0 projects withough changing the .prj or .sln projects.

Comment: @OmegaMan I tried exactly the same in VS2012 with Resharper 7.1.25.234  (official release), but I get squigglies under the style name. I would also like intellisense to work correctly (so that I can start writing the name of a style, and ctrl+space will fill in the rest). It that working for you?

Answer (score 2):

VS2012 is able to 'see' resources since VS XAML designer loads and executes your code in design-time, so VS can inspect what resources will be available at runtime. ReSharper never uses design-time code execution (since this requires your code always be in compilable state) so XAML support became a bit more complex task.

ReSharper 8.0 implemented support for BAML decompilation and do extracts the list of XAML files and resolves XAML resources from referenced binary assemblies.